# Store final set of Gnuplot fit parameters from terminal to a file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, gnuplot

I want to ask how one can store fitted values of the parameters (got from Gnuplot) to a file or print them in a file instead of just displaying them on the terminal? Thanks.

Comment: From the manual: "Once fit has finished, the `save fit` command may be used to store final values in a file for subsequent use as a parameter file." If you experience problems with that, feel free to add further details to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked. But it is showing only the last function parameters (e.g. parameters of function f7(x)), while I want to save for all the functions from (f1 to f7).

Comment: If you do not show your code, we cannot know where or how these functions f1 to f7 are defined.  Is this one fit or seven fits?  You can save whatever you like using `print` statements at any time.

Comment: `f(x)=a1*x+b1` `f1(x)=a11*x+b11` `m(x)=a7*x+b7` `m1(x)=a71*x+b71`

Suppose I use these . I used them to fit in different fit ranges. While fitting in Gnuplot I need to specify the approximate values of the variables e.g. I defined `a1=0.5; a11=0.5` and so on. 

After fitting I get the final fitted values in the terminal which I want to save again in this file (to show in legends). `save fit` option saves the value of only the last variables `a71, b71`. I want to save all these values i.e.`a1,b1,a11,b11,a7,b7,a71,b71`

Comment: I have been using script file to do tha fit and plot.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have disabled the log file by saying `set fit nolog`, the output you see on the terminal is also written to a file "fit.log".  You can change the name of the file by saying `set fit logfile "new-logfile-name"`.

As Eldrad commented, if you just want the fit parameters rather than the full output you can either use `save fit "filename"` to write them in a format that gnuplot can read back in, or `set print "filename"; print sprintf("format",A), sprintf("format",B),...` to print them in a format of your choice.

Comment: Thanks, but using 'save fit' I am able to store only the last function variables and I want to store values for all the functions I used.

Comment: @HimaniVerma As Ethan commented, you can use `save fit` several times, i.e. you could put it after each `fit` command. And did you try the last option with `set print`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried `save fit` with different filenames and then combined them using `cat` and it worked :) Thank you very much! @Ethan and @Eldrad